# Загрузка Счетов и Актов в 1С из файлов, сгенерированных в PHP

Tags: php, 1с

Имеется: 1С Предприятие 8.2 + Бухгалтерия 2.0
Нужно каким-нибудь образом загружать в 1Ску счета и акты.

В 1С не бум бум, но знаю, что наш бухгалтер все платежки из Сбербанк Бизнес-он-лайн выгружает в текстовый файл, который потом использует в 1С (через кнопку "Загрузить выписку").

Наверное как-то можно и счета и акты загружать в 1С через файл?

Скажите в какую сторону копать? Где искать решение? Сгенерировать нужные txt, excel, csv файлы я смогу на стороне php, важно найти решения загрузки их в 1С.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Загрузить выписку" = Обработка на языке 1С, которая читает файлик, выгруженный из клиент-банка и создает соответствующий документ(-ы) в базе.

Поэтому, копать нужно в сторону 1С-ника, который напишет обработку для создания Актов/Счетов из файла с данными, который предоставите ему вы.
Второй вариант: смотреть на шлюз интеграции с [1С<->1С:Битрикс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=42&CHAPTER_ID=04912&LESSON_PATH=3912.4912) (CommerceML - суть XML с синтаксисом на русском), но "из-коробки" у Битрикса обработки расчитаны на 1С:Управление торговлей, а не Бухгалтерию.
Третий вариант: поискать готовые обработки загрузки на [Инфостарте](http://infostart.ru/).

В любом случае, придется либо самому вникать в код обработок и быть готовым его править, либо искать 1С-ника.